# Image upload in HTML not working

Tags: html, post, upload

Here the code which i have used to upload the image to server.But it returns "The requested URL / was not found on this server." error.

```
<form name="uploadFile" action="http://http.brammies.com" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit="return validate();">
<input type="hidden" name="choice" value="upload">
<table align="center">
<tr>
<td><span style="color:red;font-weight:bold">Upload files</span></td><td><input type="file" id="ufile" name="ufile" onKeyPress="return false;" style="BACKGROUND-color:Thistle">(* jpg,gif,png)</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" style="BACKGROUND-color:Thistle"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Can any one tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: Possibly nothing - the server is saying it doesn't recognise the URL you have used in your `action`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL http://http.brammies.com does not refer to a form handler. From the outside, it is impossible to tell what the `action` attribute value *should* be.

From the response given by the server when http://http.brammies.com is accessed directly, it seems that the attribute value should be http://http.brammies.com/cgi-bin/ followed by some filename of a CGI script.